# how to create a macro in racket where a list becomes the args of said lambda?

Tags: list, macros, lambda, racket, define-syntax

How would I go about in doing a `define-syntax-rule` that accepts a list as arguments and a list (or a quote, in case it is a single element) as body of a lambda?
i would like to do something like:

```
    >(define a (lambdarize '(x y z) '(+ x y z)))
    #<procedure>
    >(a 1 2 3)
    6
    >(define b (lambdarize '(x) 'x))
    #<procedure>
    >(b 1)
    1
```

I have played around with `define-syntax-rule` and `apply`, but since `lambda` itself seems to be a macro and not a procedure, i have been stumped at trying to find it...

oh... And I would like a solution that does not use `eval`, as it is pernicious...

UPDATE

thanks for the answer, Ryan... that pretty much did it! =) the problem with eval was that it is no good at catching the current scope... this way i can do stuff like

```
    (let ([a 1])
        (begin
            (defmethod add ((x integer?) (y integer?)) (+ x y a))
            (add 1 2)
    )
```

which would fail miserably with eval... this is just an academic example, but i think it is a good test for correctness.

Comment: Can you say more about the context -- how/why you need/want this? Because, I don't understand the benefit of a macro to do what `define` and `lambda` can already do at _compile_ time with static lists in your source. Whereas, if you want this to work on data at _run_ time, I'm not sure I see how to avoid `eval`. But maybe I need more coffee.

Comment: well, I'm defining a sort of generic methods and I would like it to construct a body which itself would turn into a lambda at method creation with the supplied var names and body. the problem is, that to keep the syntax-rule sane, I'm avoiding to do to much on the macro and instead call a function that deals with constructing a method. Plainly, I'm defining a method like this: `(define-syntax defmethod
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(defmethod name ((var predicate)...) body)
     (add-to-generic name var... predicate... body))
     ]))` .The predicate is there to allow type checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to create a function where the formal parameters and body are given as run-time values (S-expressions) without using `eval`.

But based on your answer to Greg's comment, you can change your `defmethod` macro to avoid this issue. Your current approach takes the variables and body expression (program terms), converts them to run-time values, then wants to reinterpret them as program terms. Instead, you should just combine the program terms into a `lambda`-expression in the macro, which you can then pass as a value to the helper function:

```
(define-syntax-rule (defmethod name ((var predicate) ...) body)
  (add-to-generic name
                  (list predicate ...)
                  (lambda (var ...) body)))
```

If you wanted to keep the variable names around (eg for error messages), you can also quote them, but separate from the `lambda`-expression:

```
(define-syntax-rule (defmethod name ((var predicate) ...) body)
  (add-to-generic name
                  (list predicate ...)
                  '(var ...)                 ;; for errors, debugging, etc
                  (lambda (var ...) body)))
```

Comment: This answer is from the Mai Pei of Racket macros -- master of the five point palm exploding syntax technique. ;)